Samsung Galaxy S24 not working for react native Android app
React Native Android application is not working in Samsung Galaxy S24 and A55 after installing from Play Store. The app freezes on the default launcher screen.
I found the solution of making the app 64-bit compatible but it is already compatible.
Here is my Gradle file:
splits {
    abi {
        reset()
        enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
        universalApk false // If true, also generate a universal APK
        include “armeabi-v7a”, “x86”, “arm64-v8a”, “x86_64”
    }
}

Even when I extracted the APK file, I found all 4 folders in the lib folder.

Things to try, possibly obvious but not assuming anything:

Is the app working on other 64 bit devices?
Does arm64-v8a contain all expected .so files?
Run logcat > app.log, then launch the app. Stop log cat.
Locate the app's bundle id in the output, determine the PID of the process.
Filter app.log by the PID.
Look for any exception/stack trace information.
Does the app connect to an api on startup? Connectivity or misconfiguration be causing the hang.
You haven't said whether you are the author of the app. Assuming you are, compare the logcat output in dev and production to find any differences.
Try running a production build locally on the device.

Not an answer, but a few avenues of investigation to get you started.

Yes, I am the author of the app. When I run the app directly from Android Studio, it works perfectly, even with a signed build. However, after installing the app from the Google Play Store, we encounter the following issue: The app freezes on the default launcher screen.

You can use logcat within Android Studio and filter for your app ID, it should work even with the play store version. You basically want to look for anthing with a stacktrace.
Without an exact error message (and stack trace) or knowledge of your app and packages, no one is going to be able to give you an answer.

We had the same problem. Our solution was to upgrade the react-native version of our project to the latest version.
